# Kotlin: How to "port" one class that extend List of object and method that work with generics, from c # to kotlin?

Tags: c#, kotlin, porting

I need to port a library from C # to Koltin but I have a class that I don't know how to "translate", any suggestions?

```
 public class MyClass: List<IMyInterface>
    {
       
        public T[] myMethod<T>() where T: class, IMyInterface
        {
            List<T> myList = new List<T>();

            foreach (IMyInterface element in this)
            {
                if (element is T)
                    myList.Add((T)element );            
            }

            return myList.ToArray();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The direct translation from this would derive directly from `List` but then you would need to implement all the abstract methods, and since C# `List` is equivalent to Kotlin `ArrayList` you can simply derive from it like the following.

```kotlin
class MyClass : ArrayList<IMyInterface>() {
    fun <T: IMyInterface> myMethod(): Array<T> = toTypedArray() as Array<T>
}
```

Although you can accomplish it with an extension method like this.

```kotlin
fun <T: IMyInterface> List<IMyInterface>.myMethod(): Array<T> = toTypedArray() as Array<T>
```

Notice that you'll get a warning in both scenarios since you're doing an unchecked cast from `T` to `IMyInterface`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the suggestions of Android Studio, the method made me translate it like this:

```
    inline fun <reified T : IMyInterface> myMethod() : Array<T>{
        val myList : MutableList<T> = mutableListOf()
        this.forEach { element ->
            if(element is T){
                myList.add(element)
            }
        }
        return myList.toTypedArray()
    }
```

Comment: Notice that the original code does the cast anyways. Also it is an instance method for `List<IMyInterface>` and not a global scope one.